# error: incompatible types: MapsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou tentado adicionar o fragmento do API Google Maps no tela principal do projeto

error: incompatible types: MapsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

parte do código:

```
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.container, new MapsFragment(), "MapsFragment" ) ;

    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

O erro aparece quando eu do o comando New.. fala que não pode ser convertido em fragmento..

como faço pra usar ele na tela principal então ?

Answer (score 0):

Eae, acabei de me deparar com esse problema, a solução foi adicionar um import

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

no lugar de `import android.app.Fragment;`
No caso, da classe Fragment que ira chamar.

Após isso ainda me ocorreu outro erro, onde o aplicativo fecha ao clickar no evento que me levaria ao fragment,logo creio que pode ter ocorrido com vc.
a solução é:
Precisamos chamar e implementar os métodos dessa interface `OnFragmentInteractionListener` para cada classe que sera chamada como fragment.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, PrincipalFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener ,QuemSomos.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

No meu caso adicionei a `MainActivity` e usei o alt+enter para gerar.
Espero ter ajudado depois disso tudo funcionou perfeitamente.Abraço e não se esqueça de marcar como melhor resposta se essa resposta foi útil pra você.